# Post multipart/form-data file from stream with HttpClient

Tags: c#, multipartform-data

**The problem:** Is it possible using httpclient to post a HttpPostedFileBase(only available in memory, not on disk.) to another endpoint?

**What I've tried:**

I have the following controller, we are posting in a file from our frontend and it binds to the file parameter.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public async Task<Stream> Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //file is not null here, everything works as it should.

        //Here im preparing a multipart/form-data request to my api endpoint
        var fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(file.InputStream);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            formData.Add(fileStreamContent);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://restapi.dev/api/files/add", formData);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to pass this request on to another application that's not publicly available(so we can't post directly from the client)
That controller looks like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/files")]
public class FilesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("add")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Add(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //This is the problem, file is always null when I post from my backend.
        var files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

`file` is always null, so are `files`.
What am I missing? When I use postman and post directly to the API endpoint, it works. So im guessing that im doing something wrong in my `HomeController`?

Comment: So this is a simple proxy onto another server? What is the first controller? MVC/ WebAPI? Could it be WebAPI?

Comment: Yeah exactly, the first controller is a MVC controller and the second one is a WebAPI controller. I can change the type on both of them if that would make it easier to solve the problem. Ideally i would just like to passthrough the first request straight to my api controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve on this with newer tech.

In webapi, you can write a controller method like this:

```
//[Route("api/Foo")] //maybe?
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyResourceProxy(HttpRequestMessage request)
```

now you can take that request and rewrite its `RequestUri` property:

```
request.RequestUri = new Uri(blah);
```

new up an `HttpClient` and forward the request:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
//make sure that this fails if it's hung for more than 30 seconds
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
try
{
    response = await client.SendAsync(request,
                                      HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, 
                                      cts.Token);
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout);
}
```

make sure that everything gets disposed:

```
request.RegisterForDispose(new IDisposable[] {request, client, cts, response});
```

and then return the `response`

```
return response;
```

I added a timeout mechanism in that might not be appropriate for you needs.

Comment: This looks really nice, it's working, kind of. Im recieving the following error(from my api) 
```{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://restproxy.dev/api/files/add'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'files'."
}``` 

That's weird because if I try to access that url directly in the browser, it works. It feels like the request im doing in my controller looks in the wrong application, somehow...will investigate further!

Comment: @JOSEFtw It looks like you may need to also change the `request.Headers.Host` property.

Comment: yep! That was it. Thanks for your solution man, it's really clean. Have a nice day!